# Most efficient way to count complex "filtering" sql query

Tags: mysql

My query I'am quite sure that the easiest way will be to remove some select columns - well its a filter grid query so no idea if worth, for sure add a LIMIT 1
and the count would be on the index id, what do you think about it? Just to make it a smooth not a long executing query.

```
    $fquery = $db->query("SELECT zlec_status.nazwa                       AS Status, 
       piorytet.nazwa                          AS Priorytet, 
       Concat(koord.imie, ' ', koord.nazwisko) AS `Koordynator`, 
       Concat(zlec_adresy.miasto, ' - ', zlec_adresy.ulica, ' ', 
       zlec_adresy.oddzial) 
                                               AS `adres`, 
       zlec_z_dnia,zlec_id,
       zlec_nr, 
       zlec_do, 
       zlec_ogran, 
       awizacje, 
       awizacja_na_dzien, 
       termin_zamkniecia, 
       tresc, 
       uwagi 
FROM   zlec 
       INNER JOIN koord 
               ON zlec.koord = koord.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_adresy 
               ON zlec.zlec_addres = zlec_adresy.id 
       INNER JOIN piorytet 
               ON zlec.priorytet = piorytet.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_status 
               ON zlec.status_zlecenia = zlec_status.id 
HAVING adres LIKE concat('%',:az,'%'), array(
            "az" => array_values($activeFilters)[0]
        ));
```

[image]

Comment: please rephrase your actual question, it's not clear from your question description.

Comment: Please paste output of `EXPLAIN SELECT zlec...` query, so we will see what indexes MySQL has chosen to use.

Comment: @Marki555 never did that before can you be more specific

Comment: execute the same query, but prepend `EXPLAIN ` before it. The result from mysql will be the execution plan - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: `HAVING adres` without a `group by` doesn't make sense at all.